# Bad UNC when cifs mounting of netapp share on linx

Tags: cifs, syslinux

While mounting the cifs mount as below getting "mount.cifs: bad UNC"

```
mount -t cifs 192.168.56.24:/cifsnetapp_share /cifs -o credentials=/root/secrets/secrets,gid=5103,_netdev,vers=3.0,cifsac
```

Can you all please help me

Comment: Which  distro and version of Linux are you running?

Comment: RHEL7.9 Linux  Storage is shared from from netapp

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information.

Answer (score 1):

A correcter syntax is (mind the `//` before IP address and the `:` is to be avoided):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.56.24/cifsnetapp_share /mnt -o  credentials=/root/secrets/secrets,gid=5103,_netdev,vers=3.0,cifsac
```

I never came across `cifsac` either.

Comment: Thanks for the helping hands, But I am getting below error                                                                                Mounting cifs drive gives: "mount error(22): Invalid argument"

Comment: That might be the `cifsac` .  I would try mounting without all the options and then gradually add them to find the culprit.

Comment: Yes, I do tried removing all eg.  mount 192.168.56.24/cifsnetapp_share /mnt -o username=<username>,gid=5103.       Still giving same error

Comment: No, I meant the options ie everything that appears after the `-o`.  Something like sudo `mount -t cifs //192.168.56.24/cifsnetapp_share /cifs -o credentials=/root/secrets/secrets`.  Also check the existence of a share named `cifsnetapp_share` on the server `192.168.56.24` and the directory `/cifs` exists and is accessible.